# VBA - Delete rows in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, rows

```
Function DeleteRows()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)

Debug.Print wb.Name

Dim wsName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
wsName = "SheetX"
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)

Debug.Print ws.Name


With ws
        Debug.Print "ws.name = " & ws.Name
        Rows("3:31").Select

        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End With
End Function
```

I have this function, DeleteRows, that deletes the the rows 3:31 from the worksheet "SheetX".

This only works when "SheetX" is the sheet that is displayed on the screen.

I want it to work when another sheet, lets say "SheetY", in the workbook is displayed. How can I do this?

One way would be to:
1-activate "SheetY"
2-delete the rows 
3-activate "SheetX"

But this would not be transparent to the user. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always try to avoid Select statements. They are almost always unnecessary.  That function should be a Sub (because it doesn't have an output) and can be rewritten as a one-liner:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetX").Range("3:31").Delete xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: tks, and so I should only use functions if I have an output(or I am returning something from the function)?

Comment: There is a good explanation on this [here](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Functions-And-Subroutines.html), which I have copied: "The main difference between a VBA function and a VBA subroutine is that a function returns a result, whereas a subroutine does not.  Therefore, if you wish to perform a task that returns a result (eg. summing of a group of numbers), you will generally use a function, but if you just need a set of actions to be carried out (eg. formatting a set of cells), you might choose to use a subroutine."